# Best practice for starting an activity as an intent with extras

Tags: android, android-activity

When creating a fragment, it´s recommended to use a static method inside the fragment class also to pass and wrap arguments (s.[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/4367848)).

Now I thought about sth similar for starting an activity with an intent.

f.e.:

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends AppCombatActivity {

    public static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    public static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    public static void startAsIntent(Context context, String param1, int param2) {
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        extras.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        extras.putInt(ARG_PARAM2, param2);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it that I know of. Others have suggested doing the same thing. It has the advantage of allowing you to perform more validation before setting up the extras (e.g., checking the size of a `Bitmap` so you know that you won't go over the 1MB IPC transaction limit).

Comment: I've done it this way with no issues. Especially if the Activity *needs* the parameters that you're passing in.  It shows explicitly what is needed so it's far less confusing.

Comment: I've seen this quite a bit.  I actually like it if there's complex logic to filling in the extras that would otherwise need to be repeated multiple places.

Comment: I think just calling the method `start` is more concise because you aren't starting an Activity "as an Intent", you are using the Intent simply to "start" the Activity

Answer (score 3):

This is completely correct, maybe the misunderstanding is caused because the data bundle must be received by the `Activity`. And now since some API´s ago we have fragments and sometimes is necessary open an `activity` ( and send a bundle with data) from the `Fragment`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use direct pass data to intent ,bundle best use for fragment,
Check following example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
intent.putString(ARG_PARAM1 ,value); 
intent.putInt(ARG_PARAM2 ,value);
```

I hope help this

Comment: i know, but i needed to put a serializable, so i used a bundle. To show you an example I changed the code and stayed with the bundle.